# On the conditions for Artin-Schelter Gorenstein algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Let $ k $ be a field and $ A $ a connected graded $ k $-algebra ($ A $ is associative, but not assumed to be commutative).

The algebra $ A $ is called Artin-Schelter Gorenstein* of dimension $ d $ if the following conditions hold

(1) $ A $ has finite injective dimension $ d $ considered as an $ A $-module from both sides, left and right.

(2) $ \operatorname{Ext}^i_A(k, A) \cong 0 \cong \operatorname{Ext}^i_{A^{op}}(k, A) $ for all $ i \neq d $.

(3) $ \operatorname{Ext}^d_A(k, A) \cong k[l] \cong \operatorname{Ext}^d_{A^{op}}(k, A) $ for some integer $ l $.

Question: Do the conditions (2)+(3) imply (1)?

The reason for asking this question is because I can check (2) and (3) by hand: $ k $ often gets an easy enough resolution by free $ A $-modules. On the other hand (1) is impossible to check.

Also, if $ R $ is a more familiar commutative Noetherian local ring with residue field $ k $, then $ R $ having finite injective dimension is equivalent to the ext groups $ \operatorname{Ext}^i_R(k, R) $ vanishing in all degrees except one, where it is $ k $ (and these equivalent statements define $ R $ Gorenstein).

*The reference is Artin and Schelter's original paper in 1987.